# "Let random variables $X_1,\dots, X_n$ be a iid random sample from $f(x)$" - what does it mean?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sampling, random-variable, iid

In books it is often written, Let random variables $X_1,\dots, X_n$ be a iid random sample from $f(x)$. What does it mean?

Are $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ different values of one random variable $X$ which follows distribution $f(x)$, or all of them are different random variables?

If I have a dataset of 1000 persons' height (normally distributed) and $X$ is height of an individual and if I take a random sample then what are $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$? What does the term iid means?

Comment: A random sample from a finite population is not an iid sample unless you specify that the sampling is _with replacement_ meaning (among other things) that it is possible to pick the same person more than once. In the standard meaning of "the phrase", $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ would the heights of 10 different people from the set of 1000 people whose heights have been recorded in your dataset.

Comment: I am little bit confused, if X1,X2,…,Xn are realized value of a rv X~f(x) then how X1,X2,…,Xn are called random variable?

Comment: The second paragraph of your question asks about something that is different from the query in the third paragraph.

Comment: I am a little bit confused here regarding the second paragraph.. If X1,X2,…,Xn are realized value of a random variable X taken as a random sample from a population which have distribution f(x), then why books write these realized values as random variable X1,X2,…,Xn instead of x1,x2,...,xn (realized value)? how the realized value are random variable?

Comment: Some textbooks do write realized values as for example $P(X = x_1), P(X = x_2), ... $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct, $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are $n$ independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) values of the same variable drawn from the same distribution $f(x)$.

The term "i.i.d." means the values of $X$ are completely independent (the probability that $X$ assumes a particular value for record $i$ is unrelated to the values of $X$ for other records) and all values of $X$ are random pulls from the same distribution (e.g., the normal distribution with a given mean and variance).

Comment: It seems like one perhaps implicit issue raised by the OP is whether $X_i$ are *random variables* from a given distribution, or samples of a common random variable $X$.

Comment: @AntoniParellada - Yes the notation can be confusing. Sometimes $X_1, X_2, ...$ refers to completely separate variables (e.g., height, weight, etc.) from different distributions while in other cases $X_1, X_2, ...$ are specific values of a single random variable (and perhaps ought to be written as $X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2, ...$). One clue is the notation: $X_1, X_2, ..., X_k$ typically refers to $k$ different random variables while $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ refers to $n$ values of the same random variable.

Comment: RobertF I am now thoroughly confused. How can I tell whether $X_1,X_2,X_3$ refers to $k=3$ different random variables or $n=3$ values of the same random variable?

Comment: @DilipSarwate - I look at context. For example, if you're reading a textbook or paper about multiple regression then it should be clearly stated that $X_1, X_2, ..., X_k$ are separate predictor variables. If you're studying sampling distributions with/without replacement from a univariate distribution (like height of an individual) then it ought to be clearly specified that $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are random variables from the same distribution which may or may not be i.i.d. depending on whether you're sampling with/without replacement.

Comment: @RobertF Oh, come on! That is a nonsensical response. You said "One clue is the notation: $X_1, X_2, ..., X_k$ typically refers to $k$ different random variables while $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ refers to $n$ values of the same random variables."  So I ask you again: How can I tell whether $X_1,X_2,X_3$ refers to $k=3$ different random variables or $n=3$ values of the same random variable? I have used _your_ notation exactly. So, tell us, pretty please: what is the clue that your notation is providing to help us to distinguish between the two cases?

Comment: @DilipSarwate - $n$ typically refers to the number of records in a dataset, while $k$ often refers to the number of variables. If all you have is $X_1, X_2, X_3$ then there's nothing in the notation to tell the difference except context.